# Asp.net works on mobile device

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile, mobile

I asked to get clarify, I have an asp.net site it works great.
Site Contains many pages ,what I aim to do, is to make this page works on mobile device.
The Real problem it, my page contains many and many controls, So there is messy in the page .

First I want to know, how can I make page on asp.net works on mobile device?

Second ,Is it should to create a new one to get few of controls of the main page , because on the mobile page I need only few of the original .

Update:- 
my site is responsive 
But I have a specific page which have a lot of controls and it looks messy in appearing on mobile , So I need to create a new page similar to this page with fewer controls appears only when user use mobile not web browser.

Sorry for bad English, or being not organized.

Answer (score 0):

Browser sniffing is not reliable. You should look to redesigning your site as RWD (Responsive Web Design). Use Nuget to bring in Twitter Bootstrap and start from there.

Here's an example using Web Forms (MVC would be similar):

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-0-0-with-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: I have this plugin already but I need to get only few of controls from page or make new one with small controls,how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to make a particular page with specific controls, then add Twitter and your custom CSS style sheet to a new master page just for that page.

Comment: Sorry for being dummy, it does mean to create new aspx page with new master page and add to the new master page bootstarp and CSS, and in my new page add new controllers ?

Comment: Yes, give it a try and let us know if this is really what you want. By that, I mean it makes little sense in having a single RWD page in an otherwise desktop site.

Comment: thanks for you precious time, last question, shall I name the new page with name of the old page, if yes, how would browser different them?

Comment: You do NOT want to use browser sniffing. If your page is designed right, it will render correctly on ANY device (basics of RWD).

Comment: I know what you mean, but as I said my page has many and many controls, but I need few of them to make new page, because its messy in appears of of these controls on mobile

Comment: You'll have to update your question with more details and be more specific on  what is is you are trying to do. Your site is either RWD or not.

Comment: I update my question , and yes I my site is RWD, but as I said, there is a specific page looks messy when it appear on mobile , and I need to create a new one with fewer controls